# Summary Of Failures for Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am getting 2 emails a day with  report of these summary of failures.I have gone in and changed the notification settings like the emails reccomends to do. As soon as I remove the trigger and go to a different page it puts itself back. There is not option to save that I see other then removing the trigger, but it puts itself back.I have also marked the emails as spam and as junk, nothing stops them!

I want to stop recieving these emails!

Comment: it sounds like you may have code that's creating the trigger.  Search for `ScriptApp.newTrigger`

Comment: You can't really stop receiving the emails unless you change your email address but you can delete them with the Gmail API.